# Is there a SoQL DISTINCT or equivelent directive

Tags: soql, socrata, soda

For the URL based query in Socrata's SoQL is there a SQL equivalent of DISTINCT.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`$group`](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/queries/group.html) to get something pretty similar. For example: `https://data.agency.gov/resource/abcd-1234.json?$select=type&$group=type`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same use case. I just figured out that if you are using soda-java lib, you can build soqlquery like this:

```
new SoqlQueryBuilder()
            .addSelectPhrase(field1)
            .addGroupByPhrase(field1)
            .build();
```